# Фильтрация массива

Tags: javascript, массивы, dom

Есть таблица с данными и массив. Данные из этой таблицы хранятся в массиве.Как по клику по кнопке "удалить", удалять этот объект из массива?

```
var contacts = [{name:"Mark",surname:"Otto",username:"@mdo"},
                {name:"Jacob",surname:"Thornton",username:"@fat"},
                {name:"Larry",surname:"the Bird",username:"@twitter"}]
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Имя</th>
      <th scope="col">Фамилия</th>
      <th scope="col">Username</th>
      <th scope="col">Очистить</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
      <td><button>удалить</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
      <td><button>удалить</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
      <td><button>удалить</button></td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: каким образом связаны данные в массиве и в таблице?

Comment: Здесь, в примере они не связаны, связаны они в приложении, которое я пытаюсь написать. Есть форма с инпутами "имя", "фамилия", "никнейм" после заполнение которой юзер нажимает кнопку "добавить", после чего данные записываются в массив contacts и с него уже, с помощью другой функции рисуется таблица. 
Сейчас я добавила в таблицу кнопку "удалить" напротив каждого контакта и хочу, чтобы по нажатию на неё этот контакт удалялся из массива. Но не знаю как это можно реализовать.

Comment: Нужна функция, которая рисует таблицу

Comment: @АннаТот JQ Можно использовать?

Comment: @Grundy здесь всё целиком, функция updateTable
http://plnkr.co/edit/1bwPlt0nTnDL3pTf17EF?p=preview
Я пока jq не знаю, только чистый js пока учу

Answer (score -1):

```js
var contacts = [{
    name: "Mark",
    surname: "Otto",
    username: "@mdo"
  },
  {
    name: "Jacob",
    surname: "Thornton",
    username: "@fat"
  },
  {
    name: "Larry",
    surname: "the Bird",
    username: "@twitter"
  }
];
buildTable();

function buildTable() {
  let tableTbody = $(".table.table-striped tbody");
  contacts.forEach(function(item, index) {
    let tr = `<tr >
                <th scope="row">${index + 1}</th>
                <td>${item.name}</td>
                <td>${item.surname}</td>
                <td>${item.username}</td>
                <td><button data-index="${index}">удалить</button></td>
              </tr>`;
    tableTbody.append(tr);
  });
  initEvent();
}

function initEvent() {
  $(".table.table-striped tbody button").click(deleteTr);
}

function deleteTr() {
  $(this).closest("tr").remove();
  contacts[$(this).data("index")].flagRemoved = true;
  console.log(contacts);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">Имя</th>
      <th scope="col">Фамилия</th>
      <th scope="col">Username</th>
      <th scope="col">Очистить</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```